# disable list dates jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I use date range calendar: **daterangepicker.com**

There is a method to disable date (for example: 2016-02-06 and 2016-05-22 ) when I select start date? I pre-disable dates in function: `renderCalendar()` and push class: off and disable and it is working. But - how disable next dates when I click start date? I try append class (off and disabled) in function `clickDate()` but not appended... Anyone help me?

Or maybe there is other a jquery library to select range in datepicker, where  can I disable various dates in click and init?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score -1):

You can try jQuery ui date picker
 https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max

Comment: I dont want disable range dates, I would like to disable various date (2016-01-05  and 2016-02-08 , 2017-02-22 etc ).

Comment: You will be able to do that by removing data-event and data-handler by querying the date based on the following <td class=" " data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="0" data-year="2016"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">12</a></td>